# mongoid and mongomapper with eventmachine

Tags: ruby, mongodb, eventmachine

I'm very new to eventmachine and I haven't been able to find an answer to this question online.

Right now I've been using em-mongo with eventmachine, and I've written essentially a poor man's mapper between documents and their respective objects. I just wanted to confirm that mongoid and mongomapper can not be used in an eventmachine environment because they are blocking and thus defeat the point of using eventmachine in the first place, and that I'm not wasting my time writing these mappers. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a quick peek at the mongoid and mongo_mapper source code, you would be correct. My approach would be to just clone mongoid (or mongomapper) and swap out the blocking http connections with async connections. The majority of the framework details are not tied to the async http connection and should be re-usable. Good luck!

Comment: I ended up just settling with my implementation, I don't really need most of the features that mongoid or mongomapper provide. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4):

EventMachine Synchrony might be what you want:

https://github.com/igrigorik/em-synchrony

It supports Mongoid and I guess makes it thread safe.  Haven't personally tried it but it looks promising with active development.